# Retrieve generic types from other one in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a `Resource` interface which has some `translations`.
This is my "record base" for translated models.
And I have similar interfaces for "real" records, like products:

```
interface Translation {
    locale: string
}

interface Resource<T extends Translation> {
    translations: T[]
}

interface ProductTranslation {
  locale: string,
  title: string,
  status: number
}

interface Product {
  translations: ProductTranslation[]
}
```

I want to write a "generator" function which will return a getter for the translation attribute given, for instance, in vanilla JS :

```
function getTranslationValue(locale, key) {
  return (resource) => {
    const translation = resource.translations.find(t => t.locale === locale)
    return (translation && translation[key]) || null
  }
}
```

The only way I found to write it in TS needs to declare 2 generics types :

- the resource type (`R<T>`)
- the resource translation type (`T extends Translation`)

Like this :

```
function getTranslationValue<R extends Resource<T>, T extends Translation>(
    locale: R['translations'][number]['locale'], 
    key: keyof R['translations'][number]
) {
    return (resource: R) => {
        const translation = resource.translations.find(t => t.locale === locale)
        const value = translation && translation[key]
        return value ?? null
    }
}
```

Then, I can use it like this :

```
const getTitle = generateGetTranslationValue<Product, Product['translations'][number]>('en', 'title')
getTitle(myProduct)
```

Is there a way to get rid of the `Product['translations'][number]` declaration, so the call looks like this :

```
const getTitle = generateGetTranslationValue<Product>('en', 'title')
getTitle(myProduct)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jcalz ! I wonder if my case isn't a bit different because `T` in my example is directly related to `R` : `R['translations'][number]` is always `T`, so maybe there is a way to get rid of this second generic type..?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean and I may be wrong : it seems silly to me to write `myMethod<Product, Product['translations'][number]>(myArgs)`, because the call will always looks like this : `myMethod<Something, Something['translations'][number]>(myArgs)`, so I wonder if there is a way to update the function definition / the `Resource` interface to avoid that. But maybe this has to be partial type inference, which is not supported (so my question should be closed as duplicate). Anyway, here is a TS playground for my example if anyone want to give it a try : https://shorturl.at/klnpV

Comment: I might be missing something, but I think you can simplify it if you adjust your functions: `getTranslationValue<T extends Translation>(locale: string, key: keyof T)` and `const getTitle = getTranslationValue<ProductTranslation>('en', 'title')`. The latter should still accept a product as an argument.

Comment: @ionut-t indeed ! I also have to update the return function for ` (resource: Resource<T>)` , but it works. I would have preferred to pass the `Product` directly in generics, but at least it is working :) thanks !

Comment: Okay, deleted previous comments and backing up.  If you really want to compute `T` from `R` but have `R` constrained to `T` that won't work easily, but you could have `R` constrained to `Translation` and then compute `T` from it (and put it inline if you want), for example as [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NB124w) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: this is exactly what I want, you can write up an answer, thank you ! And from what I see, we can replace `Extract<...>` with `Resource<R['translations'][number]>` directly, the result looks to be the same, right ?

Comment: They are different in the return type of the function. Do you want `getTitle()`'s parameter to be of type `Product` or of type `Resource<ProductTranslation>`?

Comment: Oh got it, I'd say `Product` because this is the type given in the initial function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function really isn't [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in two type parameters, at least conceptually. You have one type parameter, `R`, that you'd like to manually specify with a type argument when you call the function, like `getTranslationValue<Product>(⋯)`. What you've called `T` seems to be identical to `R['translations'][number]`, so you can just use that directly.

Of course, without a `T` you can't [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `R` to `Resource<T>`.  But luckily since `Resource<T>` is *covariant* in `T` (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)) you can just constrain it to `Resource<Translation>` instead. That gives you

```
function getTranslationValue<R extends Resource<Translation>>(
  locale: R['translations'][number]['locale'],
  key: keyof R['translations'][number]
) {
  return (resource: R) => {
    const translation = resource.translations.find(t => t.locale === locale)
    // const translation: Translation | undefined, oops, 
    const value = translation && translation[key] // error
    // ------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Type 'keyof R["translations"][number]' cannot be used to index type 'Translation'.
    return value ?? null
  }
}
```

which unfortunately doesn't directly work. TypeScript decides that `resource.translations` can just be widened to `Translation[]`, which is accurate but not generic enough for your needs. You really want it to be something like `R['translations'][number][]` so that `find()` returns a `R['translations'][number] | undefined`.  You can explcitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type yourself, and it works:

```
function getTranslationValue<R extends Resource<Translation>>(
  locale: R['translations'][number]['locale'],
  key: keyof R['translations'][number]
) {
  return (resource: R) => {
    const translations: R['translations'][number][] = resource.translations;
    const translation = translations.find(t => t.locale === locale)
    const value = translation && translation[key]
    return value ?? null
  }
}

const getTitle = getTranslationValue<Product>('en', 'title');
// const getTitle: (resource: Product) => NonNullable<string | number> | null
```

Or you could rewrite things so that `resource` is seen as type `Resource<R['translations'][number]>` as well as `R`, which looks like this:

```
function getTranslationValue<R extends Resource<Translation>>(
  locale: R['translations'][number]['locale'],
  key: keyof R['translations'][number]
) {
  return (resource: Extract<R, Resource<R['translations'][number]>>) => {
    const translation = resource.translations.find(t => t.locale === locale)
    const value = translation && translation[key]
    return value ?? null
  }
}
const getTitle = getTranslationValue<Product>('en', 'title')
// const getTitle: (resource: Product) => NonNullable<string | number> | null
```

where `Extract<R, Resource<R['translations'][number]>` uses [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to "filter" `R` by `Resource<R['translations'][number]>`. It will look just like `R` from the caller's side (so `Product` and not `Resource<ProductTranslation>`), but inside the function the compiler sees it as assignable to both types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpTiAzgGzmYAexGQG8AoZZHQhOHCALmSzClAHNyBfc80SLEQoAShCyEArlCQAeVMggAPSCAAmWNBmx4CxAHxlKyNplz4i2ZqgDaAXR58B0eEmQAFKITWSEYdGa6lkZUNHQMzKzsIBwANMYEYBEsbJzxVKz4kljMIJIAtgBG0I784C7CHl4+fiEm2uZ6VlXevv4NQcT2pSBw+eIADpUAYsBQrADKkAN1MJIgfsEcEO2BFsQAavSSELIiiioQ6ppiEtJyATrrIPr6ABTGobT0TMgiNgDkpldNWB92NjyRWgAI+YRe-3SVGQAGsIABPZhw+GEGBvT7fRqWP4AoHFKAOKgASjqVCgK2kJDu5LOMleIhJAF5DBRodCEMRWPU1k1kIzkDSpHSAHSYzrYYUwUBqO5gPmGMDC8EMPmM-nKiBEx7QgD0OuQHOwcrF12sHWuyAAPsh5moIFKQBA1LFkIRCAMsC7tVRDVyAG7bFD8k28gBkoe5P0sNmRdmQesUUC8UG98f1AFpM1nsznc1nDAA-IvFkulguphOoeEDFAfZGo9EAIhD2MbuIK+LsHwNmBAhDlxRtWCdJkIyGlyhM1drlyxxA+wtT5LAlOQAZwO2QAH4t8g8jgcNreFReMZfXLlv5gEkg8hL7PxVsN7tPK0-PcPkcPi6vteGB8iQAbmMBNzzvFZUD-V5qXEIUkGYV8ajAJlDEweFSnIXp+iwIY3FGJQAEZZnmRZiHA1Yo02QM9gOVQNDeWDzl2B9rluB42Q1Zh3i+c1fn+QEOxBT4NUhbVkSRBEG24ltOX4vEQWMElWWhZdVxg2l4LeFDSXZTljV47EuIxAzZPbYECXsPkBUYkUZOwYC2R9PTIznEhgxMiUHRlOVmRMJVnhVNV1QCzVUzA9dN3cnlgnDFzxRjBE4yXCkoBICKUB3PdJAPI9jFPJyjXIyCbys+8PKfHZZEQtoPy-H9En-ICQP1MD7yg5h1Lg15qr8bSADliD67K8EKBhZCiTgrSy8zDGtfdD1PLDBhGYAlAAJmIhZeTK6KqOfGjlDok4bIuDy2O1Tj0R43bsDkwSLLBELRLZcTYUktFpI8nEBPMwlkCU7VVNS5BOqY5gAFEVAwPw9hdU4ur2Yybu++SCVubTlLZMC7KswUmNFL7JWlWV5T8jVVWC8JQscg1nPSqycdiuyEvhP62SBtLA23Xd5tyk8z2ctqSv5HbKJACqX2qGq7k-EBv2QX8bwA5racKoXklBukEKl3rSYGkAhoPOBRt2CaYim1HZqynLHCAA)

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed explanation and useful links, I learned a lot from it and will continue for a bit :P